# Scala Implicit convertions: 2 way to invoke

Tags: scala, operators, implicit

@lucastex [posted](http://lucastex.com.br/2009/10/22/maravilhas-do-groovy-elvis-operator/) about the Java Elvis operator, and I tried something in Scala to get the same effect.

I've just converted everything to a new Structural Type with the `?:` operator taking an object of the same type as argument. So Say:

```
implicit def toRockStar[B](v : B) = new { 
                            def ?:(opt: => B) = if (v == null) opt else v}
val name: String = "Paulo" // example
```

Why `name ?: "Lucas"` gets `"Lucas"` and `name.?:{"Lucas"}` gets `Paulo`? The new Structural Type is supposed to return the initial value of anything if it **is not null**, that is, `"Paulo"` in the above code.

I'm a bit confused. Any explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your operator ends in `:`, which means it reads right to left when in infix notation. For example:

```
scala> 1 :: Nil == Nil.::(1)
res2: Boolean = true
```

All methods read left to right in dot notation, though. So you are actually applying your method to `Lucas` in the infix notation, and to `name` in the dot notation.

By the way, the Elvis operator was [not accepted](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-August/002173.html) for inclusion in Java 7.

Comment: Oh Gosh! You'r right! Page 223 in O'Reilly Programming Scala. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the record (finding this thread while searching back the following article...), Daniel Spiewak (another famous Daniel in the Scala world...) posted an article about [Implementing Groovy’s Elvis Operator in Scala](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/implementing-groovys-elvis-operator-in-scala).